# change device-model without root

Tags: device-name

i want to change the device-modell of a non-rooted device.

is there ANY way to do it (that doesnt involve rooting)?

maybe also an app that sends that the device is compatible.

Comment: You should edit your question and elaborate in detail what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

By device model do you mean Android version? In this case, it is possible without root, but you will be left with the company. Some companies offer Android upgrades (to the latest version) for devices. To attempt to get the latest version of Android:

Go to Settings > About > System updates > Check for update.

If it says "upgrading" or "updating" you might be in luck!

If not... there really isn't much else you can do. Unless you want to try root, a custom recovery, and flashing a new version of Android (besides voiding your warranty, this could hard-brick your device). Or contact the company and see if they offer Android upgrades for your device model.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: **No.**
Because without root you can't change manufacture info that made by company.

**But,** there are some apps that can simulate it with built-in function. For example:
During Covid-19 there was problem with video's quality. If your device wasn't in list,then you couldn't watch videos at 720p and above. There is an app called **YouTube Vanced**. This app could simulate supported device model on devices that weren't in list. And thanks to this function all YouTube Vanced users could watch all videos on max quality. It means that you can change model number without root if that function available on program.